# Error: Expected initializer before "file", including ifstream.

Tags: c++

Not really sure what the error is here. This is standard file opening that I've used all the time before. The right things are being included. And it's just a regular ifstream. What is wrong with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

struct item{
    string item;
    string type;
    int price;
    }

ifstream board;
board.open("messageBoard.txt");

}
```

Comment: sure it compiles?

Comment: `int price;
    }` missing a semi-colon

Comment: ANSWER: The end of a struct needs a semicolon too. Oops.

Comment: And `using std`  is bad - google that

Answer (score 1):

wow! no one can notice that??!!

```
int main(){

struct item{     // 
    string item; // error C2580: redefinition of class name 'item'
    string type;
    int price;
    } // missing a semicolon here `;`
```

you are using the class name as another identifier so you get a compile-time error `redefinition`

so you can make them different:

```
struct Item // 
{
    string item; // now it's ok Item is not item
    string type;
    int price;
};
```